# Why is my LinkedHashMap being incorrectly converted to JSON and saved in SharedPreferences?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gson, sharedpreferences

I'm trying to save an object in SharedPreferences but first converting the object to JSON as shown below. However, the object is being both incorrectly converted and saved.

```java
    private void saveSchedule() {
        String jsonString = new Gson().toJson(schedule);
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("Schedule", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString("schedule", jsonString);
        editor.apply();
    }
```

The JSON looks like this:

```
E/ {"com.example.****.****.HobbyApp@a64232":["Hobby1","Hobby2","Hobby3"]}
```

This makes it impossible to save and retrieve the schedule.

Why is the name of the schedule file address being converted into JSON and saved instead of the values? Please help, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON only supports strings as JSON object property names. Gson therefore by default calls the `toString()` method to convert non-String `Map` keys to strings.

If instances of your `Hobby` class can easily be represented as string, you could override its `toString()` method. For deserialization you will however likely have to register a custom [`TypeAdapter`](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/TypeAdapter.html).

Otherwise you can uses [`GsonBuilder.enableComplexMapKeySerialization()`](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/GsonBuilder.html#enableComplexMapKeySerialization()) which will serialize your `Map` as JSON array.